# Its possible to modify a datagridview to this?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to create an interface similar to this mock-up (sorry, drawing is not my thing). It was impossible for me to create " the component" in the second column, the one with the link-buttons and and the formatted text. Is there any way to do this or some third-party component to do something similar?

[The mock-up](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/7444/dibujopyp.png)

Answer (score 0):

This should be easily possible using [Template Field](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs) (this is assuming that you are talking about ASP.NET application)

Comment: No, its just a simple windowsForm app.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're looking into the DataRepeater control

It is part of the VIsual Basic Power ToolPack but it is a .net control so it will work from C# as well.

Here is a detailed video showing an example of almost exactly what you're trying to accomplish.
http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=30534